# How to remove a property from JS object

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

How can I remove a property from a variant object in Smart Pascal?

In JavaScript I can remove a property with the delete keyword
`delete obj['myProp']`.

How to do it in Smart Pascal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smart allows you to directly execute JavaScript code by reusing Delphi's `asm` syntax.

```
asm
  delete @obj['myProp'];
end;
```

The `@obj` syntax is necessary if you are referring to a Smart Pascal entity because the actual name may be something else than `obj` due to obfuscation. During compilation, `@obj` is replaced with the actual name of the entity.